# TypeScript create generic callback type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc

Say I have this function definition:

```
export type ErrorValueCallback = (err: any, val?: any) => void;
```

a standard callback interface.  And I can use it like so:

```
export const foo = function(v: string, cb:ErrorValueCallback){
    cb(null, 'foo');
};
```

But what if want to make this callback generic, something like this:

```
export type EVCallback = <T>(err: any, val: T) => void;
```

that syntax works, but when I try to use it:

```
export const foo = function(v: string, cb:ErrorValueCallback<string>){
    cb(null, 'foo');
};
```

I get an error

> ErrorValueCallback is not generic

how do I what I am looking to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the generic to the *type* `type ErrorValueCallback<T>`

## Fixed example

```
export type ErrorValueCallback<T> = (err: any, val: T) => void; // FIX

export const foo = function(v: string, cb:ErrorValueCallback<string>){
    cb(null, 'foo');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to use EVCallback instead

```
export type EVCallback<T> = (err: any, val: T) => void;
```

like this:

```
export const foo = function(v: string, EVCallback<string>){
    cb(null, 'foo');
};
```